# Best way to fire different functions for different window sizes

Tags: jquery, performance, if-statement

I have a site, that behaves in different ways for mobile and desktop devices. I could use this selector to choose wether to fire functions:

```
if($(window).width < 768) {
    // fire functions for mobile
} else {
    // fire functions for desktop
}
```

How does this snippet work, if I write a lot of stuff into the placeholders? Does it skip the whole `if` or `else` code (to reduce loading time)?

Should I create variable functions like so, to keep it clean, or should I trigger everything my `if {} else {}` function?

```
// Is this one better?
if ($(window).width() < 768) {

    // $('something').something();
    // var another = $('another');
    // another.something();
    // lets guess lots of stuff to do here
    // like 200 lines of code

} else { 

    // $('something').something();
    // var another = $('another');
    // another.something();
    // lets guess lots of stuff to do here
    // like 200 lines of code
}

// Or this one?
var mobileFunctions = function() {

    // $('something').something();
    // var another = $('another');
    // another.something();
    // lets guess lots of stuff to do here
    // like 200 lines of code
}
var desktopFunctions = function() {
    // $('something').something();
    // var another = $('another');
    // another.something();
    // lets guess lots of stuff to do here
    // like 200 lines of code
}
if ($(window).width() < 768) { 
    mobileFunctions();
} else { 
    desktopFunctions();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and best answer: write the code first to be clean and maintainable, and profile and measure it after if you need things to go faster.

That said, I think you're fussing over areas that are never going to show up in a profiler. If you're worried about the cost of a function call that spans like 200 lines of code, then that's like worrying that a smidgen of dirt on a race car is going to slow it down by making it a gram heavier when you could be tuning the engine instead.

Micro-level things that might be worth worrying about (after measuring) would be things like cache-friendly memory access and sometimes (rarely) branch prediction. You also typically want to look for big loops when you're tuning for micro-efficiency, like some small piece of code that is executed a million times over in a loop.

As for the nature of the if statement, that's generally going to be close to free. The hardware we're using these days attempts to predict what your instructions are going to do. When the predictions are correct, the cost of branching drops to nil or close. In your case, a mobile device never becomes a desktop, and a desktop never becomes a mobile device while the application is running, so it's completely playing to the branch predictor.

About functions calls in general, generally speaking, you shouldn't think about them having a cost, and you especially shouldn't until after you've profiled your code. But sometimes having more functions can actually speed up your code, as counter-intuitive as it sounds. If you embed a massive amount of code into a single monolithic function, then you could hinder performance with increased icache misses (somewhat like excessive inlining in languages like C or C++).

It's all very compiler specific, and if your JIT is a trace compiler, then things are very different. But especially because compilers vary a lot in this world, your best chances for performance will often hinge on writing code in a more normal kind of way (not dumping hundreds of lines of code into one function to avoid a function call). That should be your baseline, default way of writing code, until your measurements tell you that you can selectively tune specific areas. Put simply, you're often better off even from a sheer performance perspective to favor a more maintainable way of writing code than to start obfuscating it based on preconceived hunches about performance lacking any measurements whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I may have thought, that javascript is heavier than it actually is.